# How would you analyze a HTML string to be valid

Tags: html, xss

I have a form which get user input as HTML (BB or similar solution won't do, I have no control).
For now I need to make sure ALL tags are closed, so it won't kill my page's html layout.
The simplest solution I have in mind is to show ONLY the snipet I get from the user in an iFrame.
Is there a better approach?
(Again, I have **no** control on that specific input and how I get it).

Comment: if you pass the string to jQuery `$('<div>....</div>')` it will create a valid dom tree

Comment: but if I pass `'<div><font>ddfdfdfdf</div>'` or `'<font>fddfdfd'`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would check for and allow only certain tags (such as "<B>" or "<I>" as examples). If you want to allow all html you could use a client side tool such as "https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/". I'm not sure what server side technology you are using but you are going to want to clean/sanitize there as well.

In addition to checking whether or not the layout is proper - if the html ever comes from an untrusted source - you are going to need to watch script tags to prevent against XSS or other security risks. See this page for more details (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer). I know that isn't the exact question, but it is really important to check for.